# How Implement IOC in a Go project

Tags: go, inversion-of-control, solid

I'm trying to implement some of the best code practices in a Go project, and I know that Go have he particularities, but I think that I'm found the right way to do it, but have one point that bother me.
I create a repository package with an interface like below:

```
type IItemsRepository interface {
    ListItems() (items []entities.Item)
    GetItemByID(id uuid.UUID) (item entities.Item)
    CreateItem(item entities.Item)
    DeleteItem(item entities.Item)
    UpdateItem(item entities.Item)
}
```

It implementation is below:

```
type ItemsRepository struct{}

func (ir ItemsRepository) ListItems() (items []entities.Item) {
    items = []entities.Item{}

    db.Instance.Find(&items)

    return items
}

func (ir ItemsRepository) GetItemByID(id uuid.UUID) (item entities.Item) {
    item = entities.Item{}

    db.Instance.Where(&entities.Item{ID: id}).First(&item)

    return item
}

func (ir ItemsRepository) CreateItem(item entities.Item) {
    db.Instance.Create(item)
}

func (ir ItemsRepository) DeleteItem(item entities.Item) {
    db.Instance.Delete(item)
}

func (ir ItemsRepository) UpdateItem(item entities.Item) {
    db.Instance.Save(item)
}
```

At this point I don't see any problem, but now let's see how I have implemented the IOC, I did created a package called ioc with this function that will resolve all project dependencies:

```
func ResolveDependencies() {
    container.Singleton(func() repositories.IItemsRepository {
        return &items_repository.ItemsRepository{}
    })
}
```

And now I have a problem, in every function that will use the item repository I should call a function that resolve the dependency, like bellow:

```
var itemsRepository repositories.IItemsRepository

func Execute(input AddItemInput) models.ResultWrapper[AddItemOutput] {
    container.Resolve(&itemsRepository)

    item := mapItem(input)

    itemsRepository.CreateItem(item)

    output := AddItemOutput{
        ID: item.ID.String(),
    }

    return models.ResultWrapper[AddItemOutput]{
        Success: true,
        Errors:  nil,
        Data:    output,
    }
}
```

How you will implement IOC without call the dependency resolver in every function?

A better way to implement IOC in Go.

Comment: You can create factories and work out an ioc implementation, however, ioc solves the kind of problem that is common in framework driven languages, which go is not. So instead of trying to port a solution suitable for an IOC, try to solve it in a way more idiomatic for Go.

Comment: That said, there are IOC libraries for go, and you can give them a try.

Comment: https://github.com/google/wire